# Casting types with Flows comment syntax

Tags: flowtype

I have this function:

```
([key, value]) => key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)
```

And get the error, that `value` is `mixed` but `encodeURIComponent` expects `string`.

I'm using Flows comment syntax, so I tried this:

```
([key, value /*: string */]) => key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)
```

which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type annotation for function params goes between the parameter and the optional default value, e.g.

```
var fn = (param = 45) => {};
```

would annotate as

```
var fn = (param: number = 45) => {};
```

So in your case `[key, value]` is `param`, so the annotation goes after that as

```
([key, value] /*: [string, string] */) =>
```